# Drush not runnig on ubuntu18.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, drush

while running Drush command on ubuntu 18.10 it gives

> Command 'drush' not found, did you mean:
>
> command 'rush' from deb rush
>
> Try: sudo apt install

I install composer globally and used $ composer global require drush/drush installed drush

```
$ composer global require drush/drush
```

drush --version?

Answer (score 0):

the [guide](https://docs.drush.org/en/7.x/install/#composer-one-drush-for-all-projects) examples all include some kind of version at the end of the global require statement

`composer global require drush/drush:dev-master`

then you add composer to your ~/.bashrc or ~/bash_profile file

`export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

If the above does not work please review the [drush installation guide](https://docs.drush.org/en/7.x/install/#composer-one-drush-for-all-projects).

Comment: you're welcome, please let us know which was missing for future readers.

Comment: Actually, I missed the exporting path. so doing this it worked and see this (https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/570) also